# Adding relationships in NSManagedObjectModel to programmatically created NSEntityDescription

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsentitydescription

When you write a static library which uses CoreData there's a big mess including a normal .xdatamodeld file into the project because you simply cannot just link its compiled version (.momd) into your binary, so it's better to create the whole `NSManagedObjectModel` in the code like this:

```
NSAttributeDescription *dateAttribute = NSAttributeDescription.new;

dateAttribute.name = @"timestamp";
dateAttribute.attributeType = NSDoubleAttributeType;
dateAttribute.optional = NO;
dateAttribute.indexed = YES;

NSAttributeDescription *payloadAttribute = NSAttributeDescription.new;

payloadAttribute.name = @"payload";
payloadAttribute.attributeType = NSBinaryDataAttributeType;
payloadAttribute.optional = NO;
payloadAttribute.indexed = NO;

NSEntityDescription *entry = NSEntityDescription.new;

entry.name = entry.managedObjectClassName = NSStringFromClass(MyCustomEntry.class);
entry.properties = @[dateAttribute, payloadAttribute];

NSManagedObjectModel *mom = NSManagedObjectModel.new;

mom.entities = @[entry];
```

And everything is just perfect....

But! Wait, if I have more than one entity in my `NSManagedObjectModel` and they are related (to-many, inversed, and so on), how in the world I gonna connect them in the code, like in example above, without that nice Xcode editor, where you make relationships with several mouse clicks?

**Example**

Imagine, we have a class MyCustomElement, which is almost the same as in MyCustomEntry from the code above. Now, here're their interfaces how they would appear if I used Xcode generation for entities:

```
@interface MyCustomEntry : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *payload;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyCustomElement *element;

@end

@interface MyCustomElement : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *entries;

@end

@interface MyCustomElement (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addEntriesObject:(MyCustomEntry *)value;
- (void)removeEntriesObject:(MyCustomEntry *)value;
- (void)addEntries:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeEntries:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

What NSRelationshipDescription I need to create for them and how to init it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Relationships are described by `NSRelationshipDescription` objects. The following code creates two entity descriptions for "MyCustomEntry", "MyCustomElement" with relationships

- `entries` (MyCustomElement --> MyCustomEntry, to-many),
- `element` (MyCustomEntry --> MyCustomElement, to-one), inverse of `entries`.

Both entities have only a string attribute "identifier" (to save some lines of code).

**Objective-c:**

```
NSEntityDescription *entry = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
[entry setName:@"MyCustomEntry"];
[entry setManagedObjectClassName:@"MyCustomEntry"];

NSAttributeDescription *entryIdAttribute = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
entryIdAttribute.name = @"identifier";
entryIdAttribute.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;

NSEntityDescription *element = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
[element setName:@"MyCustomElement"];
[element setManagedObjectClassName:@"MyCustomElement"];

NSAttributeDescription *elementIdAttribute = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
elementIdAttribute.name = @"identifier";
elementIdAttribute.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;

// To-many relationship from "Element" to "Entry":
NSRelationshipDescription *entriesRelation = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];

// To-one relationship from "Entry" to "Element":
NSRelationshipDescription *elementRelation = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];

[entriesRelation setName:@"entries"];
[entriesRelation setDestinationEntity:entry];
[entriesRelation setMinCount:0];
[entriesRelation setMaxCount:0]; // max = 0 for to-many relationship
[entriesRelation setDeleteRule:NSCascadeDeleteRule];
[entriesRelation setInverseRelationship:elementRelation];

[elementRelation setName:@"element"];
[elementRelation setDestinationEntity:element];
[elementRelation setMinCount:0];
[elementRelation setMaxCount:1]; // max = 1 for to-one relationship
[elementRelation setDeleteRule:NSNullifyDeleteRule];
[elementRelation setInverseRelationship:entriesRelation];

[entry setProperties:@[entryIdAttribute, elementRelation]];
[element setProperties:@[elementIdAttribute, entriesRelation]];

NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
[mom setEntities:@[entry, element]];
```

**Swift** (now updated for Swift 3/4):

```
let entry = NSEntityDescription ()
entry.name = "MyCustomEntry"
entry.managedObjectClassName = "MyCustomEntry"

let entryIdAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
entryIdAttribute.name = "identifier";
entryIdAttribute.attributeType = .stringAttributeType;

let element = NSEntityDescription()
element.name = "MyCustomElement"
element.managedObjectClassName = "MyCustomElement"

let elementIdAttribute =  NSAttributeDescription()
elementIdAttribute.name = "identifier"
elementIdAttribute.attributeType = .stringAttributeType

// To-many relationship from "Element" to "Entry":
let entriesRelation = NSRelationshipDescription()

// To-one relationship from "Entry" to "Element":
let elementRelation = NSRelationshipDescription ()

entriesRelation.name = "entries"
entriesRelation.destinationEntity = entry
entriesRelation.minCount = 0
entriesRelation.maxCount = 0  // max = 0 for to-many relationship
entriesRelation.deleteRule = .cascadeDeleteRule
entriesRelation.inverseRelationship = elementRelation

elementRelation.name = "element"
elementRelation.destinationEntity = element
elementRelation.minCount = 0
elementRelation.maxCount = 1 // max = 1 for to-one relationship
elementRelation.deleteRule = .nullifyDeleteRule
elementRelation.inverseRelationship = entriesRelation

entry.properties = [entryIdAttribute, elementRelation]
element.properties = [elementIdAttribute, entriesRelation]

let mom = NSManagedObjectModel()
mom.entities = [entry, element]
```

I have tested this code and it seems to work, so I hope that it will be useful to you.

Comment: Kudos to @idanuda for adding a Swift version!